# How to get the text entered in search in action bar to a string?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create an action bar with search.
I am able to create the search bar. How I can get the text entered in the field to string? Is there any good code for action bar with search?

What I done is

```
SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String search = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the search bar as like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.

        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```