# Android Actionbar SearchView

Tags: android

I have tried the actionbar SearchView in android.
Unable to get the entered string from the below code please anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing **onQueryTextSubmit** code to:

```
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null Query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Query is:" + ""+query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590015/1937802)

You can use the search bar as like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.

        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```