# SearchView with ViewPager adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

I have one activity with three fragments. I'm using `ViewPager` with tabs. One fragment is a `SearchFragment` with a `ListView`. It sends query to Service class and then, after the service is done it calling a custom adapter and shows the results. The problem is, that i don't know how to access the `SearchView` from the `SearchFragment`, how to get the query, that the user has entered.
Thnx.
Main Activity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Do something
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            query = searchView.getQuery().toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "Main query is " + query);

            SearchFragment fragment = (SearchFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("search");
            fragment.beginSearch(query);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return true;
}
```

Fragment code:

```
public void beginSearch(String query) {
    Log.e(TAG, "got query "+ query);
    Intent intent;
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    String search = sp.getString("search", "a");
    if (search.equals("Free search")) {

        if (connection == NOT_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet connection. Can`t search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            if (query.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class);
                intent.setAction(Service.ACTION_SEARCH_BY_TEXT);
                intent.putExtra("query", query);
                getActivity().startService(intent);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                editor.putInt("refresh", SEARCH_BY_TEXT);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    } else if (search.equals("Search nearby")) {
        if (connection == NOT_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet connection. Can`t search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (query.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class);
                intent.setAction(Service.ACTION_SEARCH_NEARBY);
                intent.putExtra("query", query);
                intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
                intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
                Log.e(TAG, "lat" + lat + "lng" + lng);
                getActivity().startService(intent);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                editor.putInt("refresh", SEARCH_NEARBY);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19590015 modify and use this

Comment: This is the code that i have in my Activity, but i need to get the query in the fragment...

Comment: then you just write a function in your activity and call from your fragment.

Comment: i tried it, and it didn't work for me...

Comment: what you have tried, i think there is some issue in your code, because most probably your are switching fragment from your activity so you can surly get it worked

Comment: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5514856

Comment: I've edited the question and added my code